# MySQL - put many names into a 1 same group

Tags: mysql

- **member & groupMember** table

  [image]
- My current query

  ```
  SELECT g.groupName, IFNULL(m.name, '') name
  FROM groupMember g
  LEFT JOIN member m ON g.groupID = m.groupID 
  AND m.className = '1A'
  ```
- My current output

  [image]
- My expected output

  [image]
- How should I modify the query in order to get the above expected output?

Comment: [group_concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Why do you want such output? Putting two items in the same "cell" should be work for "presentation layer" - your app code, preferably in some view or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use as per below-

```
SELECT g.groupName, group_concat(m.name) name
FROM groupMember g
LEFT JOIN member m ON g.groupID = m.groupID 
AND m.className = '1A'
group by g.groupName
```